# Partial match of strings, operator ( =~ )

Tags: regex, string, perl, compare

I have used " =~ " to compare two strings (The length of two strings is the same.) in my script to allow a don't care condition. If a character is "." in a string, that character is ignored to compare.  In other words, it is a partial match case.

comp_test.pl :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

my $a=".0.0..0..1...0..........0...0......010.1..........";
my $b="10.0..0..1...0..........0...0......010.1..........";
my $c=".0.0..0..1...0..........0...0......010.1..........";

if ($a =~ $b) {
print "a and b same\n";
}

if ($a =~ $c) {
print "a and c same\n";
}
```

Because of don't care condition by ".", the expected result should be both "a and b same" and  "a and c same". However, currently, the result is only "a and c same". Please let me know any good operator or changing "." to "x" may help?

Comment: =~ is the matching operator not a compare Operator what you Need is eq to compare strings

Comment: I understand. The partial matching is what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `.` matches `1` (or any other character), `1` doesn't match `.` (or any other character other than `1`).

---

The following is a fast solution. It performs best when most strings match (since it always checks the entire string).

```
sub is_match { ( ( $_[0] ^ $_[1] ) =~ tr/\x00\x1E\x1F//c ) == 0 }

say is_match($a, $b) ? "match" : "no match";
say is_match($b, $c) ? "match" : "no match";
```

How it works:

```
    Hex of characters
    =================

    30 30 31 31 2E 2E  "0011.."
    30 31 30 31 30 31  "010101"
XOR -----------------
    00 01 01 00 1E 1F
       ^^ ^^           2 mismatches
```

This solution even works if one of the strings is shorter than the other (since the XOR will result in `30`, `31` or `2E` for the extra characters).

---

The following is a fast solution. It performs best when most strings don't match (since it stops checking as soon as a match is impossible).

```
sub make_matcher {
   my $pat =
      join '',
         map { $_ eq '.' ? $_ : "[.\Q$_\E]" }
            split //, $_[0];

   return qr/^$pat\z/;
}

sub is_match { $_[0] =~ make_matcher($_[1]) }

say is_match($a, $b) ? "match" : "no match";
say is_match($b, $c) ? "match" : "no match";
```

---

Tested.

Comment: Thank you. I like these solutions. Both work perfectly. One quick question is which one is faster? I think the second solution is faster because it stops  as soon as a match is impossible.

Comment: If there was an easy answer, I wouldn't have posted both solutions. It depends on the data.  Using `^` + `tr///` is a fair bit faster than building and using a regex pattern. But if you reuse the pattern returned by `make_matcher`, and if your strings are very long, and if there's usually a mismatch early on, that might not matter. Also note that `make_matcher` can be modified to check if a string matches one of multiple other strings at the same time. Therefore, you'll need to benchmark with realistic data if it matters enough to spend the effort.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a perl version problem.  You are doing a regular expression match.  The operand on the left of the `=~` is the string and the operand on the right is the regex being applied to it.

This can be used for the kind of partial matching you are doing, given that the strings are the same length and each character of the regular expression matches a character of the string, but only where there is a `.` on the right.  Where there is a `1` or a `0` in the regular expression (`$b` in the case of `$a =~ $b`), there must be an exactly matching character in the string (`$a`), not a `.`.

To do the kind of partial match you seem to want to do, you can use a bitwise exclusive or, like so:

```
sub partial_match {
    my ($string_1, $string_2) = @_;

    return 0 if length($string_1) != length($string_2);

    # bitwise exclusive or the two strings together; where there is
    # a 0 in one string and a 1 in the other, the result will be "\1".
    # count \1's to get the number of mismatches
    my $mismatches = ( $string_1 ^ $string_2 ) =~ y/\1//;
    return $mismatches == 0;
}
```

Comment: @ikegami do you have sample strings that it gets wrong?  Assuming the characters are limited to 0, 1, and ., the results of ^ are going to be \0, \1, \36, or \37, and ony \1 indicates a 0 and 1 conflicting.  (It may very well not work in EBCDIC, though)

Comment: Hence the length check :)

Answer (score -4):

From my understanding, you are trying to compare the length of 2 strings.Basically, only the length of the sting need to be compared, not the bit-wise characters.

```
my $a=".0.0..0..1...0..........0...0......010.1..........";
my $b="10.0..0..1...0..........0...0......010.1..........";
my $c=".0.0..0..1...0..........0...0......010.1..........";
```

So the code could be:

```
if(length($a) == length($b))
{
  print "match found";
}
else
{
  print "No match";
}
```